# What is the difference between these two functions: `ioremap_uc()` and `set_memory_uc`?

Tags: c, linux, caching, posix, virtual-address-space

When I want to mark memory region as Write Combined (to disable cacheable and use BIU) or Uncacheable through set PAT(Page attribute table - 7bit in PTE), then what do I must to use, and what is the difference between two these functions?

- Drivers should use `ioremap_[uc|wc]` to access PCI BARs with [uc|wc] access types: [void __iomem *ioremap_wc(resource_size_t phys_addr, unsigned long size)](http://www.takatan.net/lxr/source/arch/x86/mm/ioremap.c?a=x86_64#L229)
- Drivers should use `set_memory_[uc|wc]` to set access type for RAM ranges: [int set_memory_uc(unsigned long addr, int numpages)](http://www.takatan.net/lxr/source/arch/x86/mm/pageattr.c#L938)

Taken from: http://lwn.net/Articles/278994/

Why can't I use the same single function both for PCI BARs and RAM ranges?

**Clarification:**
Does `ioremap_uc()` get physical address and return virtual address with setting Uncacheable, versus `set_memory_uc()` which get already virtual address and set Uncacheable for these pages?

Are these codes equal?

```
void* virt_ptr = ioremap_uc(phys_ptr, size);
```

and

```
void* virt_ptr = ioremap(phys_ptr, size);
const int page_size = 4096;
set_memory_uc(virt_ptr, size/page_size);
```

Comment: Did you find anything further or get an answer to this elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Notes from the lwm article:

> -- in the above table mean "Not suggested usage for the API". Some of the --'s are strictly enforced by the kernel. Some others are not
> really enforced today, but may be enforced in future.

It's pretty clear you shouldn't use them for anything other than RAM.

Using `ioremap*()` is also wrong since there is a specific API for PCI, which is `pci_iomap*()`.
Mainteners will only make sure the right the API is working for the right intents.