# If I have only the physical address of device buffer (PCIe), how can I map this buffer to user-space?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, posix, pci-e

If I **have only the physical address** of the memory buffer to which is mapped the device buffer via the PCI-Express BAR (Base Address Register), how can I map this buffer **to user-space**?

For example, how does usually the code should look like in Linux-kernel?

```
unsigned long long phys_addr = ...; // get device phys addr
unsigned long long size_buff = ...l // get device size buff

// ... mmap(), remap_pfn_range(), Or what should I do now?
```

On: **Linux x86_64**

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17278263/1558037

> `ioremap()` maps a physical address into a kernel virtual address.
>   `remap_pfn_range()` maps physical addresses directly to user space.

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9075865/1558037

```
int remap_pfn_range(struct vm_area_struct *vma, unsigned long virt_addr, 
    unsigned long pfn, unsigned long size, pgprot_t prot);
```

[remap_pfn_range](http://dev.man-online.org/man9/remap_pfn_range/) - remap kernel memory to userspace

May be can I use it so?

```
unsigned long long phys_addr = ...; // get device phys addr
unsigned long long size_buff = ...l // get device size buff

remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, (phys_addr >> PAGE_SHIFT), 
    size_buff, vma->vm_page_prot);
```

**Question:** But, where can I get `wma`, and what I must pre-do with `wma` before call to `remap_pfn_range()`?

Comment: @Alec Teal Yes. On Linux x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux kernel, at least, versions 2.6.x use the `ioremap()` function.

```
void *vaddr = ioremap (phys_addr, size_addr);
if (vaddr) {
  /* do stuff with the memory using vaddr pointer */
  iounmap (vaddr);
}
```

You should make a previous call to `request_mem_region()` to check if that memory space is already reclaimed by another driver, and politely request that memory to be owned by your code (driver). The complete example should look like this:

```
void *vaddr;
if (request_mem_region (phys_addr, size_addr, "my_driver")) {
  vaddr = ioremap (phys_addr, size_addr);
  if (vaddr) {
    /* do stuff with the memory */
    iounmap (vaddr);
  }
  release_mem_region (phys_addr, size_addr);
}
```

You can check your ownership by checking `/proc/iomem`, which will reflect the address range and the owner of every piece of memory in your system.

UPDATE: I don't really know if this works for 64-bit kernels. It does for 32-bit. If 64-bit kernel don't have these kernel functions, they will have similar ones, I guess.

Comment: Thanks! But should I do `ioremap_uc()` instead of `ioremap()` for PCIe-device buffer to disable CPU-cache for this region? And do `ioremap[_uc|_wc]()` functions return pointer to virtual addressing **in user-space as I need**, not in kernel-space?

Comment: About `ioremap[_uc|_wc]()` I mean these: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19811237/1558037

Comment: This example, and these functions, only work in kernel mode. To access this memory from userspace maybe you can do it through /proc/mem or writting a device driver that implements the `mmap()` system call for your device.

Comment: Ok. But may be can I use directly `remap_pfn_range()` as said here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17278263/1558037

Comment: `memremap()` for newer kernels seems better approach.

Answer (score 2):

Mapping PCI resource is dependent on the architecture.

BARs are already available to userspace with the sysfs files `/sys/bus/pci/devices/*/resource*`, which support `mmap`.

This is implemented by the function `pci_mmap_resource` in `drivers/pci/pci-sysfs.c`, which ends up calling `pci_mmap_page_range`.

Comment: Thanks! Do I need only use `pci_mmap_resource()` to remap whole any of BARs(BAR01/23/45) from the sysfs files `/sys/bus/pci/devices/*/resource*` to userspace? Can you write a simple example of using `pci_mmap_resource()`?

Comment: Your userspace program can just open the sysfs files. These functions are not exported for drivers.

Comment: Ok. If my device has a **8GB BAR**, then at boot time in `/sys/bus/pci/devices/*/resource*` will be allocated PTEs for 8GB range?

Comment: And do I need to use `msync()` to send (flush) data to device from memory?

Comment: BARs are mapped uncached; *_wc files are mapped as write-combining.